# How do I make my window.history.back() function ignore href="#"?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I do to make my `window.history.back()` function in JS not to be affected by a `href="#"` I have in my HTML?

Because now when I first hit the `href="#"` in the bottom of my webpage I come back to the top of the page(as it was intetioned). But then when I hit the `window.history.back()` function I am directed back to the `href="#"` at the bottom of my page when I actually want to get directed to a previous page.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Back to top</a>
```

---

```
<button class="klick" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
```

JS:

```
function goBack() {window.history.back();}
```

Thankful for the help.

Best regards Jelly

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be to make clicking on the blank anchor not actually add anything to the history, but simply *replaces* the current entry:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]').forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        window.location.replace("#");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, since clicking an anchor doesn't actually reload the page, you could simply track how many times the hash has changed, and go back that amount:

```
let goBackCount = -1;
let goBack = () => {
    window.history.go(goBackCount);
});
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
    goBackCount--;
});
```

Comment: The `location.replace` option works well. I'm not sure but I think there'll be a bug with the `goBackCount` option where if the user does reload the page, the history will be littered with any previous anchor clicks that the hashchange listener won't know about. (We could preserve this info in session storage, but that would start to get pretty overkilly.)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the current location without adding a new state to the session history. You can do this with the [location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) method, as shown below. (Alternatively, you could use [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).)

```
<a class="toTop" href="#">Back to top</a>

document.addEventListener("click", goToTop);
function goToTop(event){
  if(event.target.classList.contains("toTop")){ // Will work for multiple `.toTop` elements
    event.preventDefault(); // Because this is an anchor element w/ href attribute
    location.replace(location.href); // Navigates without updating history
  }
}
```